# How to merge multi modifications on a string?

Tags: string, merge

Say there is a string which is modified by multiple users, all users will send their operations to the server, and server will try to merge them on the string one by one.

For example, the string send to all users from the server is:

```
aaabbbccc
```

All users will see the exactly same string, and they modify them as:

```
user1: bbbccc
user2: aaabbbcccddd
user3: aaaccc
```

The modifications will send to server in order as Jsons:

```
user1:
{
    "delete": 0,
    "length": 3
}


user2:
{
    "insert": 9,
    "content": "ddd"
}

user3:

{
    "delete": 3,
    "length": 3
}
```

The server receives the operations and will merge them operations one by one based on the base string `aaabbbccc`.

I can think of a rule to adjust the operations like:

```
user1:
{
    "delete": 0,
    "length": 3
}


user2:
{
    "insert": 6,     // decreased because of previous deletion
    "content": "ddd"
}

user3:

{
    "delete": 0,     // decreased by the first deletion
    "length": 3
}
```

That means if there is a deletion/insertion, the offset of later ones will be changed if needed.

And the original string `aaabbbccc` will become:

```
cccddd
```

finally.

But I don't think if it's a good solution, because it sometimes can't adjust the operations correctly and throws some OutOfBoundException when deleting or inserting.

I wanna know if there is any good approach to do it? Or some libraries have already provided this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're approach is the correct one, but you need to figure out why it is throwing out of bound exceptions. Deletion is really the tricky aspect of it, the insertion operations shouldn't conflict with one another. It might be simpler to do all of the insertions first and then apply the deletions. I think your error might have something to do with forgetting to merge overlapping delete ranges and then applying multiple deletes where they both originally applied to the same part of the string.
(e.g., If you have a set of delete ranges `{[0, 10], [5, 20], [50, 55]}` you need to merge those deletions into the set `{[0, 20], [50, 55]}` before apply them.)